# PL/SQL - ORACLE: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, toad

I would like to insert data in a table with a timestamp column inside a PL/SQL ETL process on a oracle database Version 11.2.0.4

IF I run "Create INSERT from seletcted row" in Toad I get the following SQL Command:

```
 Insert into xxxx$1
   (ID, ITEM, ITEMSIZE, QUALITY, MATERIAL, 
    COLOUR, IMAGEURL, CREATIONDATE, SAMPLEITEMNUMBER, ITEMNUMBER)
 Values
   (111, 339079775, '1', 'Microfaser PRIMABELLE®', 'TEXTILE', 
    '1 (=creme)', 'url', TO_TIMESTAMP('27.06.2016 15:49:35.000000','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'xxx', 'xxxx');
COMMIT;
```

In PL/SQL I generate a VARCHAR2/String which looks like the same way:

```
v_sql :=
                                'INSERT INTO xxxx'
                             || p_importpostfix
                             || '  VALUES ('
                             || seq_xxxx.NEXTVAL
                             || ','
                             || v_rec.item_id
                             || ', '''
                             || v_size
                             || ''','''
                             || v_quality
                             || ''','''
                             || v_material
                             || ''','''
                             || v_colour
                             || ''','''
                             || NULL
                             || ''',to_timestamp('''|| to_char( sysdate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')||''',''DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF''),'''
                             || v_rec.vid
                             || ''','''
                             || v_rec.vid
                             || ''')';
```

If I run the procedure singulary outside the whole process, it works fine.
No errors occur.

If I run the complete process started by a database JOB I will get an ORACLE:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month error.

I have read the other thread with this issue without understanding the problem in my case.

Comment: what does the output of v_sql give you in your program? Use dbms_output.put_line to output it, if you don't have logging in your program already.

Comment: Well, I have logging in my application. I log the exceptions in a separate table. There I have the row with the defect. But the SQL looks good. I have logged it in the LOG table and before I printed the output with dbms_output.put_line

Comment: Are those jobs running in same DB or we have different DB for the the examples.

Comment: Mayby try trunc(systimestamp)

Comment: If you have logging, write out to your table the contents of v_sql, so that you can view the statement that is produced. That ought to go a long way to helping you debug your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it's the issue but it seems much easier to use literally SYSDATE.

And it seems you insert the string 'NULL'. If you want to insert the NULL value then you don't need to use the multiple single quote because the final string doesn't need single quote to insert NULL value.

```
v_sql :=
                                'INSERT INTO xxxx'
                             || p_importpostfix
                             || '  VALUES ('
                             || seq_xxxx.NEXTVAL
                             || ','
                             || v_rec.item_id
                             || ', '''
                             || v_size
                             || ''','''
                             || v_quality
                             || ''','''
                             || v_material
                             || ''','''
                             || v_colour
                             || ''','
                             || 'NULL,'
                             || 'SYSDATE,'
                             || ''''
                             || v_rec.vid
                             || ''','''
                             || v_rec.vid
                             || ''')';
```

**EDIT**

Instead of trying to build a query like that, you should use parameterized query.

```
    v_sql := 'INSERT INTO xxxx' || p_importpostfix || ' VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:7,:8,:9,:10)';
    v_null := NULL;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING IN seq_xxxx.NEXTVAL, 
                                  IN v_rec.item_id, 
                                  IN v_size,
                                  IN v_quality,
                                  IN v_material,
                                  IN v_colour,
                                  IN v_null,
                                  IN SYSTIMESTAMP,
                                  IN v_rec.vid,
                                  IN v_rec.vid;
```

Imagine if one of your value contains a `'`...

More information [on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/executeimmediate_statement.htm). I think you need an Oracle account though.

Comment: Thank you for response, but I think you mean SYSTIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE because it's not a date, it's a timestamp. I have tried that already. The problem is, that I have tu built the sql statement dynamically and the run the statement with execute immediate afterwards...

Comment: why do you have to build up the statement dynamically? Won't you have a fixed set of columns to insert into?

Comment: his table name is dynamic ;)

Comment: Where does it say that? Looks like the tablename is fixed (but the column list may differ) to me: `'INSERT INTO xxxx' || p_importpostfix || '  VALUES ('...`

Comment: The table name is `xxxxSomething`

Comment: Thanks for response - || p_importpostfix is the staging postfix for the table, so the columns are fix but the table is not and it works fine if run the procedure in Toad. In my opinion execute immediate is the way to run the query.

Comment: @soa: That doesn't prevent you from using Luc's answer. It's ok to dynamically set the table name, but that doesn't mean you have to concatenate the values as well (which is so easy to get wrong). Binding the parameter values on the `execute immediate` call is the right way to go.

Comment: @Luc: You don't need an Oracle account to view the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @sstan. I wasn't sur because I saw "Welcome Luc".

Comment: @LucM / Ditto: well, duh; I need more caffeine!

Comment: @Soa You could make your dynamic sql proof by using the bind variables as Luc et all have suggested, but also by using [`DBMS_ASSERT`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2) to ensure the tablename being passed in is valid. E.g.: `'INSERT INTO '|| dbms_assert.sql_object_name('xxxx' || p_importpostfix) || ' (<column list>) VALUES ...'`. You should also make sure you specify the columns you're inserting into; if someone were to add a column to the table, your code would fail otherwise.

Comment: @soa whoops, "your dynamic sql proof" should read "your dynamic sql statement sql injection proof"

Answer (score 1):

Can you show a DESC of the target table ?
To make sure the data types are not mismatched ?

Whenever you bulid these dynamic strings, I have always found it easier to use the "q" quote format to help reduce
all those repeated/escaped quotes ... makes it so much easier to read:

Start with the query from TOAD:

```
  Insert into xxxx$1                                                                                           
  (ID, ITEM, ITEMSIZE, QUALITY, MATERIAL,                                                                      
     COLOUR, IMAGEURL, CREATIONDATE, SAMPLEITEMNUMBER, ITEMNUMBER)                                             
  Values                                                                                                       
  (111, 339079775, '1', 'Microfaser PRIMABELLE®', 'TEXTILE',                                                   
     '1 (=creme)', 'url', TO_TIMESTAMP('27.06.2016 15:49:35.000000','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'xxx', 'xxxx');
```

Remove the semi-colon, and wrap q'[   ]' around each line:

```
  v_sql :=
  q'[ Insert into xxxx$1                                                                                            ]'||CHR(10)||
  q'[ (ID, ITEM, ITEMSIZE, QUALITY, MATERIAL,                                                                       ]'||CHR(10)||
  q'[    COLOUR, IMAGEURL, CREATIONDATE, SAMPLEITEMNUMBER, ITEMNUMBER)                                              ]'||CHR(10)||
  q'[ Values                                                                                                        ]'||CHR(10)||
  q'[ (111, 339079775, '1', 'Microfaser PRIMABELLE®', 'TEXTILE',                                                    ]'||CHR(10)||
  q'[    '1 (=creme)', 'url', TO_TIMESTAMP('27.06.2016 15:49:35.000000','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'xxx', 'xxxx') ]'||CHR(10)||
```

The CHR(10) is added just to make the string more readable - it's for our benefit. Not Oracle's.
Next, add an RTRIM, because all those extra spaces can make the string big, real quick :)
(for larger strings, I have used CLOBs using this same technique)

```
  v_sql :=
  RTRIM(q'[ Insert into xxxx$1                                                                                            ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ (ID, ITEM, ITEMSIZE, QUALITY, MATERIAL,                                                                       ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[    COLOUR, IMAGEURL, CREATIONDATE, SAMPLEITEMNUMBER, ITEMNUMBER)                                              ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ Values                                                                                                        ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ (111, 339079775, '1', 'Microfaser PRIMABELLE®', 'TEXTILE',                                                    ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[    '1 (=creme)', 'url', TO_TIMESTAMP('27.06.2016 15:49:35.000000','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'xxx', 'xxxx') ]')||CHR(10)||
```

Next, we need to put "placeholders" for each value you want to substitute:

```
  v_sql :=
  RTRIM(q'[ Insert into xxxx<tab_name>                                                                                    ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ (ID, ITEM, ITEMSIZE, QUALITY, MATERIAL,                                                                       ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[    COLOUR, IMAGEURL, CREATIONDATE, SAMPLEITEMNUMBER, ITEMNUMBER)                                              ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ Values                                                                                                        ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ (seq_xxxx.nextval, 339079775, '1', 'Microfaser PRIMABELLE®', 'TEXTILE',                                       ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[    '1 (=creme)', 'url', TO_TIMESTAMP('27.06.2016 15:49:35.000000','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'xxx', 'xxxx') ]')||CHR(10)||
```

For the rest, use bind variables:

```
  v_sql :=
  RTRIM(q'[ Insert into xxxx<tab_name>                                         ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ (ID, ITEM, ITEMSIZE, QUALITY, MATERIAL,                            ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[    COLOUR, IMAGEURL, CREATIONDATE, SAMPLEITEMNUMBER, ITEMNUMBER)   ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ Values                                                             ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[ (seq_xxxx.nextval, :1, :2, :3, :4,                                 ]')||CHR(10)||
  RTRIM(q'[    :5, NULL, SYSTIMESTAMP, :6, :7 )                                ]')||CHR(10)||
```

Next, during runtime, you replace your tablename "piece" (the ONLY reason you need dynamic sql here ... )

```
  v_runsql := REPLACE ( v_sql, '<tab_name>', p_importpostfix );
```

Now you can do a couple things ... verify the SQL by displaying it:

```
  dbms_output.put_line ( v_runsql );
```

Then execute it, using bind variables "properly":

```
  execute immediate v_runsql USING v_rec.item_id, v_size, v_quality, v_material, v_colour, v_rec.vid, v_rec.vid;
```